# multiple-cursors and return key

Tags: multiple-cursors

Within `multiple-cursors-core.el` `<return>` key is bound to `multiple-cursors-mode` which always ends multiple-cursors-mode, when I'd like to insert a new line.
I can unbind the key with

```
(define-key mc/keymap (kbd "<return>") nil)
```

But I wonder: is there more intended by binding `<return>` to `multiple-cursors-mode`, then just quiting multiple cursors mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `C-j` [bound by default to `electric-newline-and-maybe-indent`], or `C-q C-j` [just a plain hard return], to insert a hard return when using the `multiple-cursors` library.  The readme.md file contains the following excerpt:

```
To get out of multiple-cursors-mode, press <return> or C-g.
The latter will first disable multiple regions before disabling multiple cursors.
If you want to insert a newline in multiple-cursors-mode, use C-j.
```

Magnar most definitely intended that the return/enter key would exit `multiple-cursors-mode`; i.e., it is bound to `multiple-cursors-mode` which causes the minor-mode to turn off if it was active:

https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/blob/master/multiple-cursors-core.el#L468

See also https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/blob/master/multiple-cursors-core.el#L534 to examine the if/then statement.